# How to close a Print Preview Dialog?

Tags: c#, .net

I have a document printing function. I am trying to close the Print Preview Dialog form after the user presses the Print button. Once the print button in the print preview dialog is pressed, the event starts the function below to print the document. I am expecting the form to close when I call `printPreviewDialog1.Close()` but it just goes over the line and nothing happens.

But it doesn't close the print preview dialog form after the print job is done.

```
    public void _start_Print(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        printDocument1.Print();

    }
```

---

Added as requested in the comments. Initializing Print Preview Dialog

```
    private void btnPrint_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        PrintPreviewDialog printPreviewDialog1 = new PrintPreviewDialog();
        printPreviewDialog1.Document = printDocument1;

        ToolStrip ts = new ToolStrip();
        ts.Name = "wrongToolStrip";
        foreach (Control ctl in printPreviewDialog1.Controls)
        {
            if (ctl.Name.Equals("toolStrip1"))
            {
                ts = ctl as ToolStrip;
                break;
            }
        }

        ToolStripButton printButton = new ToolStripButton();
        ToolStripButton closeButton = new ToolStripButton();

        foreach (ToolStripItem tsi in ts.Items)
        {
            if (tsi.Name.Equals("printToolStripButton"))
            {
                printButton = tsi as ToolStripButton;
            }
            else if (tsi.Name.Equals("closeToolStripButton"))  // idk if this is the name of the close button im trying to programmatically close it after printing
            {
                closeButton = tsi as ToolStripButton;
            }
        }

        ts.Items.Remove(printButton);
        ToolStripButton b = new ToolStripButton();
        b.ImageIndex = printButton.ImageIndex;
        b.Visible = true;
        ts.Items.Insert(0, b);
        b.Click += new EventHandler(this._start_Print);

        printPreviewDialog1.WindowState = FormWindowState.Maximized;
        printPreviewDialog1.ShowDialog();
        printPreviewDialog1.Dispose(); //< doesnt do anything 
        closeButton.PerformClick(); // < doesn't do anything, possibly using wrong name for toolstripbutton

    }
```

---

Initializing Print Document as requested in the comments

```
    private void printDocument1_PrintPage(object sender, System.Drawing.Printing.PrintPageEventArgs e)
    {
        e.Graphics.DrawRectange(Pens.Black, 60, 60, 60,60);
    }
```

Comment: I just replaced the print button on the dialog with a custom control and added an event to handle the click of the custom `ToolStripButton` on the dialog. Now I want to close the Dialog because it doesn't automatically close after the print job is done. @HansPassant

Comment: could you post how you initialize printdocument1 and printPreviewdialog1?

Comment: @Frenchy added, please check

Comment: you do printPreviewDialog1.Dispose()  before printPreviewDialog1.Close() ??

Comment: @Frenchy i was just testing those lines, even after i dispose it, the dialog isn't "Disposed" and I can manually click on the close button. So i tried to programmatically click the close button. But I realize the problem now, the code never reaches `printPreviewDialog1.Dispose()` until I manually close the `Dialog`. So I need some method to dispose the active form in the event `_start_Print`, but this is not possible because `Cross thread operations are not valid`

Comment: The new code works just fine.  I suspect the real problem in the old code is that you had two printPreviewDialog1 variables.  One provided by the designer (the default name) and another as a local variable.  Picking good names is important.

Comment: do printPreviewDialog1.Close() close the preview dialog.. , dispose release memory of objet, i dont understant your logic....

Comment: @HansPassant thanks for guidance helped me figure it out, I posted the answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved.

I created a Global `ToolStripButton` and initialized this button with the `closeToolStripButton` in the `printPreviewDialog`.

Then I programmatically clicked this button after the print job was done.

```
    private ToolStripButton closeButton = new ToolStripButton();  <-- global variable

    private void btnPrint_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        foreach (ToolStripItem tsi in ts.Items)
        { 
            if (tsi.Name.Equals("closeToolStripButton"))
            {
                closeButton = tsi as ToolStripButton;
            }
            else if (tsi.Name.Equals("printToolStripButton"))
            {
                printButton = tsi as ToolStripButton;
            }
        }

        ts.Items.Remove(printButton);
        ToolStripButton b = new ToolStripButton();
        b.ImageIndex = printButton.ImageIndex;
        b.Visible = true;
        ts.Items.Insert(0, b);
        b.Click += new EventHandler(this._start_Printer); //<-- this starts the printer event where i "PerformClick() on the initialized closeButton"

        printprevDialog.WindowState = FormWindowState.Maximized;
        printprevDialog.ShowDialog();

    }


    public void _start_Printer(object sender, EventArgs e) // <--- then i just performed the close click here right after i hit the print button
    {
        printDocument1.Print();
        closeButton.PerformClick(); // <-- this way im not violating cross thread operations
    }
```